# dot notation params while searching mongo collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a bit weird situation. The problem is that some of the parameters in `mongo` collection defined deep inside objects.

for example (my situation now). if I search by `id`

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {id: '1234567'}}])
```

so my `queryObj` looks like this in Node service side:

```
let queryObj = { $match: { id: customerId } };
```

but now there is another param `providerID` that I need to take into consideration to `aggregate`

This is how it looks in Mongo query (and this runs fine):

```
db.getCollection('mydb').aggregate([{$match:{id:'31250044805', 'value.transactionDetail.medicalClaim.claimHeader.value.provider.providerNumber.providerID':'42344'}}])
```

How do I build my `queryObj` now in my Node.js service call?

I tried something like this:

```
if(providerId) {
    queryObj['$match]'['value']['transactionDetail']['medicalClaim']['claimHeader']['value']['provider']['providerNumber']['providerID'] = providerID;
}
```

I also tried:

```
if(providerId) {
  queryObj.$match.value.transactionDetail.medicalClaim.claimHeader.value.provider.providerNumber.providerID = providerID;
}
```

but it fails because I am referencing params on `undefined` values in the chain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` to add props to an object.

```
let queryObj = { $match: { id: customerId } };
if(providerId) {
  Object.assign(queryObj.$match, {'value.transactionDetail.medicalClaim.claimHeader.value.provider.providerNumber.providerID': '1234'});
}
```

Or, simply by using bracket notation:

```
queryObj.$match['value.transactionDetail.medicalClaim.claimHeader.value.provider.providerNumber.providerID'] = '1234';
```